# Русские меры длины

Tags: этимология

Откуда произошло название меры длины "пядь" - это понятно. А вот какова этимология таких мер, как "аршин" (тут слышится что-то тюркское), "вершок" и "верста", "сажень" (хотя, тут подозреваю какую-то связь со словом "сажать" - возможно, мера засеянной земли)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Верста** - праслав. Образовано посредством суф. -т-а, неизвестного в соврем, яз., от корня *верт-*, того же, что и в слове *вертеть*. Верста — первонач. «поворот» (плуга) > «мера длины», вначале равная расстоянию от одного до другого поворота плуга во время пахоты, затем «длина, установившаяся в размере 1,06 км».

**Сажень** - древн. слав. слово. Первонач. обозначало «меру длины в размах обеих рук», иначе «меру, равную такой длине, на сколько *сягают* распростертые руки» («маховая» сажень). *Сягать* - «доставать до чего-нибудь».

**Аршин** - тюрк. заимств.: ср. тур., тат., кыпч., тел., бараб. aršyn "аршин", чагат. aršun -- с тем же значением.

По поводу слова **вершок** Фасмер дает довольно мало информации: "1/16 аршина", уже в Домостр. Также "отверстие в избе, через которое выходит дым". Есть еще толкование первого знач. как "небольшой излишек при насыпании зерна". Скорее "верхняя фаланга указательного пальца". Этимология прозрачна, от слова *верх* (и.-е. корень *uers 'возвышенное место').